# Planning to attend a summit in UK from 17-18th of October from India

Tags: visas, uk

I have gotten an invitation e-mail from Google to attend a summit, but there is no invitation letter provided by them. Please suggest the best way to obtain a visa.

Is it possible to get a visa with just an e-mail confirmation for the Summit, flight tickets and a hotel booking?

Please let me know possible solutions; it is very important for me to attend the event.

Answer (score 5):

Documentation requirements are detailed by [GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf) where the only mention of *email* is to specify that *travel booking confirmation (can be email or copy of tickets)*. Otherwise the requirement is *All documents must be originals and not photocopies* and there are several references to *letter*.

emails are never anywhere normally accepted as *original* since so easy to replicate without any indication of whether original or copy, and so easy to forge.

However, IF your activity is covered by a [Standard Visitor](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/documents-you-must-provide) visa's conditions then you don't need an invitation.

Comment: I'm inclined to question the authenticity of that Google email invitation. In any case, if it is real, then they should be able to provide a proper letter

Comment: @pnuts and Polymer is free and open to all; it will have livestream for those unable to attend. I wonder whether the email was an open invite to all.

Comment: @pnuts as I did the edits on the Q, it lacked punctuation and seemed to suggest that the organizers had paid for airfare and hotel. I checked out Polymer first to see whether that was likely. I should disclose that I have a relative who is a VP at Google (in Palo Alto).